# Checking if a string is in an ObservableCollection of Tuple

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection  as shown below:

```
ObservableCollection<Tuple<Guid, string>> _taskCollection
```

I want to write some code that will check if a given string exists in the collection. The string is held in “TaskName” and the code I wrote looks like this:

```
_taskCollection.Select(x => x.Item2 == TaskName.Trim()).Any()
```

The problem I have is that this line of code always returns “true” regardless of whether the value in “TaskName” is in one of the Tuple’s or not. Can anyone show me what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Any` directly rather than after `Select`:

```
_taskCollection.Any(x => x.Item2 == TaskName.Trim())
```

This code:

```
_taskCollection.Select(x => x.Item2 == TaskName.Trim())
```

will return a list of `bool` which has length equivalent with `_taskCollection`, so then you call `Any`, it's always `true`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. A good explanation, so obvious now but not so last night after a day of programming.

Answer (score 1):

`Select` transforms N input items into N output items. The amount of items doesn't change here.

What you want is to filter the items. That's what `Where` is for.

Using `Where` your second query would have been correct:

```
_taskCollection.Where(x => x.Item2 == TaskName.Trim()).Any();
```

That can be shortened to the following:

```
_taskCollection.Any(x => x.Item2 == TaskName.Trim());
```

The reason is that `Any` provides an overload that accepts a condition.

And I think it really reads intuitivly: "Is there `Any` item in `_taskCollection` for which `Item2 == TaskName.Trim()`?"

Comment: Thanks for the reply and explanation. This should stop me falling into the same trap next time.